# JavaScript variable undefined outside ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

im making a simple script so a piece of code can run in a loop.

```
 var num_rows_php;
    var num_rows_sessions_php;
    var num_rows_session_php_teste;

    $.ajax({
    url: 'verify_num_rows.php',
    success: function(){
    num_rows_php = "<?php echo $my_num_rows; ?>";
    num_rows_session_php = "<?php echo $_SESSION['transaction_count']; ?>";
    num_rows_session_php_teste = "<?php echo $_SESSION['teste_num']; ?>";
    alert('num_rows_session' + num_rows_session_php);
    alert('num rows session php teste' + num_rows_session_php_teste);
    },

    });

    alert('teste fora do ajax' + num_rows_session_php_teste);
```

I only posted the relevant part here, where my problem is. So i create the variables outside the ajax function, so i can update them inside the ajax function. this piece of code is running every 5 seconds, so even if the ajax call isn't made first, the variables should update anytime. My problem is, when i do the **Alerts**inside the ajax function, the values are correct, but the alert outside the ajax function says the variable is undefined.
**`alert('teste fora do ajax' + num_rows_session_php_teste);`** is undefined, even after the code runs like 10 times. Why is this ?

EDIT :

i tried this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'verify_num_rows.php',
            success: function(){
            num_rows_php = "<?php echo $my_num_rows; ?>";
            num_rows_session_php = "<?php echo $_SESSION['transaction_count']; ?>";
            num_rows_session_php_teste = "<?php echo $_SESSION['teste_num']; ?>";
            alert('num_rows_session' + num_rows_session_php);
            alert('num rows session php teste' + num_rows_session_php_teste);
            if (num_rows_session_php_teste != num_rows_session_php)
            {
              alert(num_rows_session_php_teste);
                //   alert (num_rows_session_php);
              $('#tbody').load('table_body.php')
              $('#myfooter').load('myfooter.php')
              $('#my-list').load('mylist.php')



        }
        },

        });
```

everything inside ajax success function and the variable is undefined in the moment of the alert.

Comment: That is because of Asynchronus calls. Have a look on Sync vs Async

Comment: but if i set the variable to a value, shouldn't it stick ?

Comment: do your action in ajax success or make ajax temporary sync.

Comment: that depends on context. If the code you gave was wrapped in a function, then everytime a new num_rows_session_php_teste variable is created. so undefined everytime

Answer (score 1):

try adding async: false on your ajax function,

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'verify_num_rows.php',
     async: false,
     success: function(){
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect $.ajax to assign value to `num_rows_session_php_teste`. Since JS is async in nature, alert might get invoked before $.ajax takes place. Hence it is possible that `num_rows_session_php_teste` is undefined when accessed from alert.

Comment: This could be a comment not an answer

Comment: hm, even inside the ajax code itself, that can happen ?

Comment: No, not inside the code. Because the $.ajax gets called, then goes into success where the variables get assigned first. So inside ajax block, it would work well but not outside.

Comment: hmm this would do the job. Correct implementation !

Comment: hm now the variables have no value at all, not undefined.

Comment: That could be because `"<?php echo $_SESSION['teste_num']; ?>";` could be empty. Can you test that once ?

Comment: $_SESSION['teste_num'] = 'test'; i do this inside the verify_num_rows.php file, if i run it outside the ajax it works.

Comment: it makes no sense, the value should be there.